# how to create associative array from NOAA data

Tags: php, json, associative-array

I'm trying to convert this to an associative array with json_decode but I'm messing up somewhere.

$noaaRaw looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => { "predictions" : [ [1] => {"t":"2021-01-01 00:29", "v":"8.870", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-01 06:22", "v":"0.807", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-01 12:31", "v":"10.383", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-01 18:58", "v":"-0.402", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-02 01:11", "v":"8.988", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-02 07:05", "v":"0.720", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-02 13:15", "v":"10.374", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-02 19:41", "v":"-0.428", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-03 01:53", "v":"9.131", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-03 07:52", "v":"0.654", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-03 14:00", "v":"10.271", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-03 20:26", "v":"-0.378", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-04 02:39", "v":"9.297", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-04 08:42", "v":"0.604", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-04 14:50", "v":"10.066", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-04 21:14", "v":"-0.261", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-05 03:28", "v":"9.485", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-05 09:37", "v":"0.546", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-05 15:44", "v":"9.788", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-05 22:06", "v":"-0.103", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-06 04:20", "v":"9.699", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-06 10:35", "v":"0.440", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-06 16:42", "v":"9.499", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-06 23:00", "v":"0.061", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-07 05:16", "v":"9.938", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-07 11:36", "v":"0.265", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-07 17:44", "v":"9.259", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-07 23:57", "v":"0.202", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-08 06:13", "v":"10.193", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-08 12:38", "v":"0.022", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-08 18:47", "v":"9.121", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-09 00:55", "v":"0.284", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-09 07:12", "v":"10.464", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-09 13:40", "v":"-0.291", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-09 19:52", "v":"9.121", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-10 01:54", "v":"0.272", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-10 08:11", "v":"10.745", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-10 14:41", "v":"-0.645", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-10 20:54", "v":"9.238", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-11 02:52", "v":"0.174", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-11 09:08", "v":"10.995", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-11 15:38", "v":"-0.959", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-11 21:52", "v":"9.387", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-12 03:47", "v":"0.055", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-12 10:02", "v":"11.146", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-12 16:31", "v":"-1.151", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-12 22:46", "v":"9.494", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-13 04:40", "v":"-0.012", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-13 10:54", "v":"11.155", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-13 17:22", "v":"-1.183", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-13 23:38", "v":"9.532", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-14 05:31", "v":"0.008", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-14 11:45", "v":"11.018", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-14 18:11", "v":"-1.056", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-15 00:27", "v":"9.501", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-15 06:20", "v":"0.123", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-15 12:35", "v":"10.746", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-15 18:58", "v":"-0.785", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-16 01:14", "v":"9.406", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-16 07:09", "v":"0.327", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-16 13:23", "v":"10.356", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-16 19:43", "v":"-0.400", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-17 02:00", "v":"9.261", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-17 07:57", "v":"0.598", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-17 14:10", "v":"9.872", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-17 20:28", "v":"0.058", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-18 02:45", "v":"9.089", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-18 08:46", "v":"0.898", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-18 14:58", "v":"9.339", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-18 21:14", "v":"0.539", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-19 03:32", "v":"8.921", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-19 09:38", "v":"1.178", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-19 15:49", "v":"8.813", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-19 22:01", "v":"0.991", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-20 04:20", "v":"8.789", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-20 10:31", "v":"1.387", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-20 16:42", "v":"8.355", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-20 22:50", "v":"1.371", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-21 05:09", "v":"8.712", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-21 11:26", "v":"1.497", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-21 17:37", "v":"8.008", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-21 23:40", "v":"1.652", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-22 06:00", "v":"8.706", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-22 12:22", "v":"1.495", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-22 18:33", "v":"7.805", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-23 00:32", "v":"1.810", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-23 06:52", "v":"8.793", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-23 13:18", "v":"1.364", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-23 19:31", "v":"7.768", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-24 01:24", "v":"1.822", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-24 07:45", "v":"8.988", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-24 14:12", "v":"1.100", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-24 20:25", "v":"7.887", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-25 02:15", "v":"1.681", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-25 08:34", "v":"9.283", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-25 15:01", "v":"0.738", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-25 21:14", "v":"8.112", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-26 03:03", "v":"1.419", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-26 09:20", "v":"9.635", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-26 15:46", "v":"0.332", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-26 21:59", "v":"8.387", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-27 03:49", "v":"1.088", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-27 10:03", "v":"9.997", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-27 16:29", "v":"-0.070", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-27 22:41", "v":"8.685", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-28 04:32", "v":"0.735", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-28 10:45", "v":"10.324", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-28 17:10", "v":"-0.434", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-28 23:22", "v":"8.995", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-29 05:16", "v":"0.393", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-29 11:27", "v":"10.582", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-29 17:52", "v":"-0.727", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-30 00:03", "v":"9.311", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-30 06:00", "v":"0.088", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-30 12:11", "v":"10.734", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-30 18:34", "v":"-0.916", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-31 00:45", "v":"9.619", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-31 06:45", "v":"-0.150", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-01-31 12:55", "v":"10.748", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-01-31 19:17", "v":"-0.971", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-01 01:28", "v":"9.887", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-01 07:32", "v":"-0.290", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-01 13:42", "v":"10.597", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-01 20:01", "v":"-0.872", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-02 02:13", "v":"10.081", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-02 08:22", "v":"-0.314", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-02 14:31", "v":"10.279", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-02 20:49", "v":"-0.624", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-03 03:01", "v":"10.178", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-03 09:16", "v":"-0.235", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-03 15:25", "v":"9.837", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-03 21:40", "v":"-0.270", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-04 03:53", "v":"10.185", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-04 10:14", "v":"-0.107", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-04 16:23", "v":"9.357", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-04 22:35", "v":"0.117", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-05 04:50", "v":"10.138", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-05 11:16", "v":"0.007", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-05 17:26", "v":"8.939", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-05 23:34", "v":"0.461", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-06 05:50", "v":"10.088", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-06 12:20", "v":"0.055", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-06 18:33", "v":"8.673", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-07 00:35", "v":"0.690", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-07 06:54", "v":"10.093", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-07 13:25", "v":"-0.014", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-07 19:41", "v":"8.624", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-08 01:38", "v":"0.744", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-08 07:58", "v":"10.201", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-08 14:29", "v":"-0.213", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-08 20:47", "v":"8.777", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-09 02:40", "v":"0.619", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-09 08:59", "v":"10.386", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-09 15:28", "v":"-0.465", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-09 21:44", "v":"9.021", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-10 03:36", "v":"0.403", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-10 09:55", "v":"10.552", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-10 16:20", "v":"-0.660", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-10 22:36", "v":"9.249", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-11 04:28", "v":"0.202", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-11 10:45", "v":"10.623", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-11 17:08", "v":"-0.734", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-11 23:23", "v":"9.411", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-12 05:17", "v":"0.080", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-12 11:33", "v":"10.568", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-12 17:52", "v":"-0.671", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-13 00:07", "v":"9.496", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-13 06:03", "v":"0.057", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-13 12:17", "v":"10.387", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-13 18:34", "v":"-0.478", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-14 00:48", "v":"9.504", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-14 06:47", "v":"0.137", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-14 13:00", "v":"10.091", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-14 19:14", "v":"-0.175", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-15 01:28", "v":"9.442", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-15 07:30", "v":"0.309", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-15 13:42", "v":"9.699", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-15 19:54", "v":"0.211", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-16 02:07", "v":"9.318", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-16 08:14", "v":"0.557", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-16 14:25", "v":"9.239", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-16 20:34", "v":"0.649", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-17 02:47", "v":"9.146", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-17 09:00", "v":"0.851", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-17 15:10", "v":"8.748", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-17 21:17", "v":"1.097", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-18 03:31", "v":"8.947", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-18 09:48", "v":"1.145", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-18 15:59", "v":"8.279", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-18 22:04", "v":"1.510", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-19 04:18", "v":"8.760", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-19 10:41", "v":"1.385", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-19 16:52", "v":"7.889", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-19 22:54", "v":"1.836", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-20 05:09", "v":"8.633", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-20 11:36", "v":"1.520", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-20 17:48", "v":"7.633", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-20 23:46", "v":"2.029", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-21 06:03", "v":"8.618", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-21 12:32", "v":"1.505", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-21 18:47", "v":"7.560", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-22 00:41", "v":"2.049", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-22 07:00", "v":"8.762", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-22 13:30", "v":"1.302", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-22 19:45", "v":"7.699", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-23 01:37", "v":"1.862", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-23 07:55", "v":"9.082", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-23 14:24", "v":"0.917", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-23 20:38", "v":"8.029", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-24 02:30", "v":"1.477", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-24 08:47", "v":"9.536", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-24 15:13", "v":"0.413", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-24 21:26", "v":"8.486", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-25 03:19", "v":"0.954", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-25 09:34", "v":"10.039", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-25 15:58", "v":"-0.120", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-02-25 22:09", "v":"9.007", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-02-26 04:06", "v":"0.376", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-26 10:05", "v":"1.338", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-26 16:11", "v":"9.196", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-26 22:33", "v":"0.542", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-27 04:48", "v":"9.151", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-27 11:00", "v":"1.075", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-27 17:06", "v":"9.105", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-27 23:25", "v":"0.520", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-28 05:39", "v":"9.557", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-28 11:58", "v":"0.690", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-28 18:04", "v":"9.090", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-29 00:18", "v":"0.442", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-29 06:33", "v":"10.037", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-29 12:57", "v":"0.202", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-29 19:04", "v":"9.172", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-30 01:13", "v":"0.294", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-30 07:28", "v":"10.562", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-30 13:56", "v":"-0.361", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-30 20:05", "v":"9.358", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-31 02:10", "v":"0.069", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-31 08:23", "v":"11.089", "type":"H"},{"t":"2021-12-31 14:53", "v":"-0.936", "type":"L"},{"t":"2021-12-31 21:02", "v":"9.406", "type":"H"} [2] => ]} )
```

How do I convert that to an associative array?

```
<?php
  $noaaRaw = file('https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetter?begin_date=20210101&end_date=20211231&station=8443970&product=predictions&datum=MLLW&time_zone=lst_ldt&interval=hilo&units=english&application=Bob_S&format=json');


  print_r($noaaRaw);
  echo gettype($noaaRaw[0]['predictions'][1]);
  $noaa = json_decode($noaaRaw[0]['predictions'][1],true);
  print_r($noaa);
?>
```

Comment: First, decode the whole JSON, then access the required node of the result array. most probably `$arr=jsone_decode($noaaRaw, true); var_dump($arr['predictions'][1]['t'])`

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Neither of the excerpts you have shown are valid JSON. What do you need to do? Do you need to make some changes to the JSON? Do you need to achieve some sort of exact array structure? Something else?

Comment: @beisior, when I try your suggestion it comes back as NULL

Comment: That wasn't me, however, your question is unclear. You're showing us two different samples of the JSON data and tbh have no idea which is correct. for sure ending it with `...` means that probably none of them. Please enter **whole** content of JSON so we can know where's the bug.

Comment: @biesior question updated

Comment: Your first step should be replacing `file` with `file_get_contents` to get the actual JSON as a string. Right now you're getting an array that contains pieces of the JSON that would need to be stringed together to make it valid. After that, read [how to extract data from JSON with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php).

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry written too fast. Of course `file_get_contents()` is a solution. However, if someone's using function returning the array can just access the index of it.

Comment: @El_Vanja, that was it.  Thank you.  I though file would give me back json, it has worked with other api's

Comment: Those other APIs probably had it all stored as a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` returns an array of lines.  You want to use `file_get_contents` to get a string to decode:

```
$noaaRaw = file_get_contents('https://api.tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/prod/datagetter?begin_date=20210101&end_date=20211231&station=8443970&product=predictions&datum=MLLW&time_zone=lst_ldt&interval=hilo&units=english&application=Bob_S&format=json');

$result = json_decode($noaaRaw, true);
```

It is also possible after that, that you may need to enable [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

Comment: Works great https://3v4l.org/dtsdS using the first 3 entries from the NOAA URL you provided.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, neither of them work. The array you atre using in your example is not the array I'm getting back from NOAA.  Please see post

Comment: You can see it work in the link I just posted.  If it's not working for you then the info in the question is not correct.  Do you have error_reporting enabled?

Comment: Abra, I believe OP has trouble expressing his true needs and issues. And `$noaaRaw` is not a JSON string (check the updated question).

Comment: @EL_Vanja, I'm requesting json data from NOAA.  With what returns I'm trying to convert to an associative array.  Is the data coming back from the api call not proper json?  Is there a way to convert to either json or an associative array?

Comment: @DCR I've left a comment under the question explaining what you need to do.

Comment: @El_Vanja  I was editing at the same time.  I just skipped over the `file` thing before :-(